# Always display Energy Applet?

Tags: linux, linux-mint

My Stepdad uses Linux Mint and although he doesn't have a laptop, he would like the power/energy applet to be visible in the taskbar so he can keep track of his wireless mouse it's power status.

Could anyone tell me how to "always display the power/energy applet" in the taskbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't explicitly mention which desktop environment he is using (I assume he uses some desktop environment, not plain window manager), I assume that he uses [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/), which is the default on Linux Mint.

To display applet on Cinnamon's taskbar, you can just do the following:

1. Right-click the panel and choose "Add applets to this panel".
2. Find there an applet called "Power Manager".
3. If the applet (Power Manager in your case) is not active, right-click it and choose "Add to panel".
4. If the Power Manager doesn't still show up, check that you have Panel Launcher -applet enabled. It can be checked/enabled from Cinnamon Settings -> Applets.

**References**

- [Linux Mint Forums: Power Management Applet](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=140995)
- [Linux Mint Forums: Add programs to taskbar](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=126893)

Comment: I apologize for forgetting to mention Cinnamon, this is indeed the environment he's using. Cheers for your thorough answer. Happy new year!

Comment: @Xander Happy new year for you too!